# How to update a table from two select queries?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I tried the SQL below and I get an error. How do I make it work ? This logic works for Microsoft SQL server but not Oracle.

```
update r1
set r1.code = 7
from
(select  id s1, code from table1 where code!=7) r1
inner join
(select id s2 from table2 where sub_id = '3') r2
on r1.s1 = r2.s2
```

Error: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that you want a correlated update

```
update table1 t1
   set t1.code = 7 
 where t1.code != 7
   and exists( select 1
                 from table2 t2
                where t2.sub_id = '3'
                  and t1.id = t2.id )
```

Comment: @stack1 - Yes, fixed. I missed the fact that you were adding `s1` and `s2` as aliases.